# Correct way to drive a 12 V motor from an Arduino with an NPN transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor, bjt, npn

Looking for some help vetting my circuit design, it's been a long time from my college days messing with electrical stuff.

My plan is to have an ATMEGA328 with the Arduino bootloader driving a 12 V 400 mA motor.
I have a 5.1 V 3 A wall wart I plan to power the circuit with.
I have an "MT3608 Step-Up Adjustable DC-DC Switching Boost Converter" that I bought from a sketchy Chinese website that I will use to source the 12 volts.

I think I can do this by having the Arduino driving a low side 2N2222 transistor that has the 12 V, motor and a diode on the other side. I don't intend to PWM the motor, so the transistor switching speed doesn't matter.

Three questions:

1. Does my circuit below work?
2. Is my diode in the correct direction to protect the Arduino and transistor?
3. How do I determine the resistance of R1?

For the resistance of R1 I think it needs to be 1/20 of current of the motor. The motor has a 400 mA draw, so I think I need a 10 mA across the transistor. I think that means a 500 ohm resistor.

Circuit:

[image: Arduino driving a 12V motor]

Comment: that's quite a bit of power to dissipate for a to-92, that sucker will be hot. better to replace it with a logic level n-channel mosfet, like an irlz44n, which works better, cooler, and with less current on the GPIO.

Comment: Your DC-DC step up is the wrong way around.  Input should be on the 5v.

Comment: You want some decoupling capacitors on your ATMEGA

Comment: All of the GNDs and VCCs need connecting.

Comment: _"12 V 400 mA motor"_ - Which motor is it? Is 400 mA the stall current, the rated operating current, or the measured current with some load?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I don't know much. That's all the product page listed for it. Did find it on amazon though and someone measured the mA across it with headpressure at 130mA. So I'm guessing 400mA is it's peak power

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does my circuit below work? Is my diode in the correct direction to
> protect the Arduino and transistor?

Yes it 'works', and the diode is the correct way around. The only issue is whether the Base is getting enough current to properly turn on the transistor.

> For the resistance of R1 I think it needs to be 1/20 of current of the
> motor. The motor has a 400 mA draw, so I think I need a 10 mA across
> the transistor. I think that means a 500 ohm resistor.

You have the right idea, but a few more factors need to be taken into account:-

1. For accurate calculation of Base current you should include voltage drop in the ATmega328's output and the transistor's Base-Emitter junction.
2. On startup the motor will try to draw its 'stall' current, which is typically at least twice the rated current. If supply current is limited the motor might not have enough torque to get going if the load at stall is high.
3. To keep the transistor turned on 'hard' you need to supply more Base current because the current gain reduces as Collector-Emitter voltage drops below ~2 V, as well as reducing at high current.

Looking at the [2N2222A datasheet](https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/2N2222A.pdf) we see that the typical gain at 10 V and 500 mA is ~50, so to get 500 mA you *typically* only need 500/50 = 10 mA. But this is at a Collector-Emitter voltage of 10 V. To keep voltage drop and power dissipation in the transistor low, you need to supply enough Base current to 'saturate' it. According to the datasheet this could be as high as 50 mA for a Collector-Emitter saturation voltage of 1.0 V at 500 mA.

A single [Atmega328](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) output is rated for 40 mA absolute maximum. The datasheet says maximum voltage drop at 20 mA is 0.9 V. Extrapolation suggests <2 V drop at 40 mA, but without a spec we can't rely on it.

At 20 mA we can expect the Arduino to deliver at least 4.1 V, and the 2N2222A Base-Emitter drops ~0.7 V, so the resistance value required is ~(4.1-0.7) / 0.02 = **170 Ω**. 20 mA Base current should be enough to switch *at least* 200 mA with low voltage drop, possibly as much as 500 mA but not much more. That makes your circuit quite marginal. It might work OK or it might not - depending on the characteristics of your particular Arduino and transistor, and how much current your motor needs to start up.

To get a guaranteed Base current of at least 50 mA you could use another transistor to amplify the current. Using another 2N2222 the circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foiFrP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit less than 1 mA is drawn from the I/O pin so it should output close to 5 V. Q1 drops about 0.7 V from Base to Emitter so the voltage across R1 is ~(5-0.7-0.7) = 3.6 V. 3.6 / 0.05 = 72 Ω (I chose nearest 5% value of 68 Ω).

Comment: Your answer and the other comment makes it seem like I'm not correct to go with bjt's just because I have them on hand. I've redone the design with mosfets. I think that's the correct way to go? Link to new design: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4zv56kfi613zwp/Schematic_Hydroponics%20Watering%20Station_2022-02-26.png?dl=0

Comment: Now that I see your actual design it is obvious it was not going to work. The 74HC595 can output 6mA, not nearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

R1 is 5v from Arduino to 0.6v to Q1 base = 4.4v drop.  Typically 1/10th current to base vs motor current.  400mA/10 = 40mA. But that is too much for the Arduino pin so, 20mA it is.  4.4v/0.020A=220 ohms.

If you have a second 2N2222A, connect them in a Darlington configuration (check Wikipedia).  This will reduce the base current needed from the microcontroller and multiply the gain. You'll get a small 0.6 voltage drop to the motor vs non-Darlington version.

Your diode is fine.

Comment: Where did you get the 0.6v to Q1 base?

Will running it at 20mA cause any problems? It'll just make it slower to switch, right?

Comment: Yes, it will be slower switching and may not put out the full 400mA. The datasheet for 2N2222A says to use 15mA for 150mA load and 50mA base current for 500mA load. 

The datasheet says the saturation voltage is 0.6v typical (a base to emitter is essentially a diode, so a 0.6v drop).

Comment: Why the downvote? It needs work but at least is mostly functional. The 2N2222 is not really suited for that, it's at the limit of his working current. I'd personally use a logic level power MOSFET that can be easily driven from an AVR and can handle almost ridiculous amounts of power these days

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I'm only using the 2n2222A because I have tons of them on hand for some reason.